Access Android serial number in Fully managed mode on Android 10 and above
If I have enrolled a device in organization with Android Management API, and I have uploaded an application in managed google play and I am installing that application in devices after enrollment using the android management policies, will my app be able to access the serial number of the device on Android 10 and above?
I am enrolling device in fully managed mode.
If no, does anyone know, how can I access Device Serial number in an enterprise setting on Android 10 and above?

Does this answer your question? Android: How to programmatically access the device serial number shown in the AVD manager (API Version 8)

Yes, you can access the device identifiers e.g. serial number by using Build.getSerial() in Android 10 and above on your delegated app. Please do take note that starting in Android 10, apps must have the READ_PRIVILEDGED_PHONE_STATE privileged permission in order to access the device’s non-resettable identifiers, which include both IMEI and serial number. In addition, using enterprises.devices.get method, you can also obtain the serial number of your device in the HardwareInfo.
